# Problem with set[Left|Right|Top|Bottom]Margin for QTextBlock in QTextEdit/QPlainTextEdit

Tags: qt, pyqt

how can i set different margins for each QTextBlock in QTextEdit/QPlainTextEdit?

i tried to set it with following code:

```
class MyWidget(QPlainTextEdit):

    def func(self):
        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        while block.isValid():
            block = block.next()
            block.blockFormat().setLeftMargin(<some_value>)
```

but it's not working

Thanks

Comment: Margin means what?
you mean width? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works only fow QTextEdit, and nothing for QPlainTextEDit

Comment: Any refs to back that up? It would explain a lot, but would be nice to have this documented somewhere ...

Comment: @Almar The closest statement I could find is [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-17460?focusedCommentId=142419&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-142419), with the quote from the Qt docs coming from [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#differences-to-qtextedit).

Answer (score 1):

Try exploring the docs:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtextblockformat.html
If you have your QTextBlock, then you could use something like this:

```
QTextBlock *block = ...;
block->blockFormat()->set[Left|Right|Top|Bottom]Margin(qreal margin);
```

Please let us know if it works, as I have not tried this code.